# Best network practice for continuity, handoff, camera, clipboard, universal control, etc? [troubleshooting]

Tags: copy-paste, camera, continuity, universal-control

What settings, debugging steps, and troubleshooting workarounds should I apply in setting up my home network for continuity/handoff features?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to share my findings on troubleshooting and designing for continuity/handoff. I decided to delve into test-and-check on the network layer, as Apple seems to be picky on device-negotiation.

Starting with the assumption that Apple designs for the non-technical masses, who have a simple internet router with default settings (all on one subnet, no client isolation, mostly wifi-only), I worked my way backwards applying various network settings to see what caused problems.

Here are my best practice requirements -- for this guide I'll use a mac and iPhone as an example.

- Both mac and phone need to have Wifi and Bluetooth on, signed in iCloud, continuity/handoff enabled, rebooted
- iPhone must be unlocked at least one time after reboot (not waiting for first unlock)
- Both mac and phone need up to **5 minutes** on wifi after reboot to ensure bonjour discovery
- Both mac and phone need to be on same wifi network, actively connected (wifi on but disconnected **rarely worked**)
- Both mac and phone must be able to reach the internet (local wifi only **rarely worked**)
- Phone must not have the cellular data "on whenever possible" (5G On) set in Settings > Cellular > Cellular Data Options > Voice & Data. For my 5G plan, I set this to "5G Auto" (**"5G On" always will eagerly disconnect the phone from wifi**).
- Phone must not have "Wifi Assist" turned on. This was hard to find. Go to Settings > Cellular and scroll all the down... all the way down, then up a little. **Wifi assist on** will eagerly disconnect the phone from wifi.
- Both mac and phone must use a DNS that correctly supports local bonjour name resolution

  - Google DNS worked (8.8.8.8)​
  - Google Encrypted DNS via device profile worked​
  - Cloudflare Family DNS **did not work** (1.1.1.3)​
- Both mac and phone need to be on the same wifi subnet/24 (first 3/4 of the ip, e.g. 192.168.1.x)

  - Phone on subnet 192.168.1.x and mac on subnet 192.168.2.x **sometimes works, laggy​**
- Both mac and phone need to have subnet mask /24 of 255.255.255.0 or less (not 255.255.255.1-255)

  - Phone with subnet-mask of 255.255.255.1 and mac with subnet-mask of 255.255.255.0 **did not work​**
- The router must have client isolation disabled, meaning it's LAN client subnet-mask is 255.255.255.0 or lower

  - Router lan client subnet mask of 255.255.255.1 **did not work**​
- Both mac and LAN need to have the same ipv4/ipv6 allowed setting (phone ipv6 and mac ipv4-only **sometimes works, finicky**)
- The mac cannot be on LAN only (**works for clipboard, not for others**).
- The mac cannot be on both Wifi and LAN. The mac ignored Wifi and uses the faster conn (**works for clipboard, not for others**).
- For camera sharing, USB mac to phone **will only work** after wifi-wifi works. USB continued to work after shutting off wifi/bluetooth/cell on the phone, but not for future connections.
- For camera sharing, try macOS Facetime first (Menubar -> Video -> Camera -> iPhone) (**PhotoBooth is finicky**)
- For camera sharing, after selecting the Video -> Camera -> iPhone in the Facetime menu, it **can take up to 5 minutes for it work**, sigh. I found this when I shifted over to check email and it suddenly turned on.

To see failures / errors logs:

- Open console.app
- Click "Errors and Faults" top left under "Console.. messages"
- Then over in the search bar after the MESSAGE TYPE boxes, click, then name of your other device (settings>general>about)

Comment: This is a great use of self answered question. +1 from my standpoint ( even if some of the sentiment isn’t 100% generally applicable. Others can answer as needed if this doesn’t help or people want to curate parts of this for focus.